# Gradle error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null with Fabric MC 1.19.4

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, gradlew, minecraft-fabric

I am attempting to port the Minecraft mod Colormatic to 1.19.4, as the developer has not made any changes for ~4 months. The compilation worked when I had Gradle 7.3, but I have updated it to Gradle 8.1.1. I looked online, and the only relevant solution was to clear the caches, but it did not work. Solution is mentioned [here](https://github.com/orgs/FabricMC/discussions/2362).

Here is the full log, running `./gradlew build --info`

```
Initialized native services in: /Users/omay/.gradle/native
Initialized jansi services in: /Users/omay/.gradle/native
Received JVM installation metadata from '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home': {JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home, JAVA_VERSION=17.0.7, JAVA_VENDOR=Eclipse Adoptium, RUNTIME_NAME=OpenJDK Runtime Environment, RUNTIME_VERSION=17.0.7+7, VM_NAME=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, VM_VERSION=17.0.7+7, VM_VENDOR=Eclipse Adoptium, OS_ARCH=aarch64}
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 65238). The daemon log file: /Users/omay/.gradle/daemon/8.1.1/daemon-65238.out.log
Starting 23rd build in daemon [uptime: 1 hrs 6 mins 24.966 secs, performance: 99%, GC rate: 0.01/s, heap usage: 10% of 1 GiB]
Using 8 worker leases.
Now considering [/Users/omay/IdeaProjects/colormatic, /Users/omay/IdeaProjects/jukebox] as hierarchies to watch
Watching the file system is configured to be enabled if available
File system watching is active
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file '/Users/omay/IdeaProjects/colormatic/settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/Users/omay/IdeaProjects/colormatic/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'colormatic']

> Configure project :
Evaluating root project 'colormatic' using build file '/Users/omay/IdeaProjects/colormatic/build.gradle'.
The configuration detachedConfiguration1 is both resolvable and consumable. This is considered a legacy configuration and it will eventually only be possible to be one of these.
The configuration detachedConfiguration1 is both consumable and declarable. This combination is incorrect, only one of these flags should be set.
The configuration detachedConfiguration1 is both resolvable and consumable. This is considered a legacy configuration and it will eventually only be possible to be one of these.
The configuration detachedConfiguration1 is both consumable and declarable. This combination is incorrect, only one of these flags should be set.
The configuration :classpath is both resolvable and consumable. This is considered a legacy configuration and it will eventually only be possible to be one of these.
The configuration :classpath is both consumable and declarable. This combination is incorrect, only one of these flags should be set.
The configuration :classpath is both resolvable and consumable. This is considered a legacy configuration and it will eventually only be possible to be one of these.
The configuration :classpath is both consumable and declarable. This combination is incorrect, only one of these flags should be set.
Fabric Loom: 0.12.56
(kotlinx.metadata.jvm.KotlinClassMetadata) with version (0.4.2) was loaded from (/Users/omay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-metadata-jvm/0.4.2/8f80407e1e84727a7e7b9edd1323081c3ab1d8da/kotlinx-metadata-jvm-0.4.2.jar)
(org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor) with version (9.3) was loaded from (/Users/omay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm/9.3/8e6300ef51c1d801a7ed62d07cd221aca3a90640/asm-9.3.jar)
(org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Analyzer) with version (9.3) was loaded from (/Users/omay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm-analysis/9.3/4b071f211b37c38e0e9f5998550197c8593f6ad8/asm-analysis-9.3.jar)
(org.objectweb.asm.commons.ClassRemapper) with version (9.3) was loaded from (/Users/omay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm-commons/9.3/1f2a432d1212f5c352ae607d7b61dcae20c20af5/asm-commons-9.3.jar)
(org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode) with version (9.3) was loaded from (/Users/omay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm-tree/9.3/78d2ecd61318b5a58cd04fb237636c0e86b77d97/asm-tree-9.3.jar)
(org.objectweb.asm.util.ASMifier) with version (9.3) was loaded from (/Users/omay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm-util/9.3/9595bc05510d0bd4b610188b77333fe4851a1975/asm-util-9.3.jar)
(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper) with version (2.13.2.2) was loaded from (/Users/omay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.13.2.2/ffeb635597d093509f33e1e94274d14be610f933/jackson-databind-2.13.2.2.jar)
(com.google.gson.Gson) with version (null) was loaded from (/Users/omay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.9.0/8a1167e089096758b49f9b34066ef98b2f4b37aa/gson-2.9.0.jar)
(com.google.common.base.Preconditions) with version (null) was loaded from (/Users/omay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/31.1-jre/60458f877d055d0c9114d9e1a2efb737b4bc282c/guava-31.1-jre.jar)
(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils) with version (2.11.0) was loaded from (/Users/omay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-io/commons-io/2.11.0/a2503f302b11ebde7ebc3df41daebe0e4eea3689/commons-io-2.11.0.jar)
The configuration :mainSourceElements is both consumable and declarable. This combination is incorrect, only one of these flags should be set.
:extracting yarn-1.19.4+build.2-v2.jar
Not publishing sources jar as it was not found. Use java.withSourcesJar() to fix.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'colormatic'.
> Failed to setup Minecraft, java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 584ms
```

As said above, I tried to remove the cache, the above log being the first run after removing the cache. I'd expect different errors, because the source code is not yet supporting Minecraft 1.19.4, along with the other changed dependencies.

I am not familiar with Gradle or Java, and am mainly just playing around, so if the error is caused by the source code, there is also a GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/Omay238/colormatic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the fabric-loom naming scheme was changed after `0.10-SNAPSHOT`.
Try changing the version of loom in your `build.gradle` from `0.12-SNAPSHOT` to `1.2-SNAPSHOT`.